# Windows 8 XAML: Tint an Image object

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have an Image object. The image source is a white graphic with transparency (a rounded rectangle to be precise). What I would like is to be able to reuse the same image in different places but tint that image different colours. The best suggestion I have found so far is to draw a semi transparent rectangle over the top but this will show on the corners where the transparency is. Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: By rounded rectangle, is it a shape that can be reproduced with either a Border/CornerRadius or Rectangle/RadiusX/Y that would allow you to use the "over-the-top" suggestion you've already received? If so we can whip it up into a ContentControl and allow you to specify the color hue pretty easily. If it's a more custom shape though, you're looking at probably a little more effort.

Comment: I think its something more complicated needed. I've added a emboss effect to the image and some of the shapes with be more complicated than a simple rounded rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

With `BitmapDecoder` you can get a byte array with all pixel data, then you can manually change it by offsetting some ARGB values and save it in a new `WriteableBitmap`:

```
var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream ras = await file.Openasync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(ras);
        PixelDataProvider provider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, new BitmapTransform(), ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
        byte[] pixels = provider.DetachPixelData();
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)
        {
            pixels[i] = (byte)(pixels[i] + 72);
        }
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.OrientedPixelWidth, (int)decoder.OrientedPixelHeight);
        using (Stream stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
        }
        image.Source = bitmap;
    }
}
```